# How to use height syntax in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, height

Let me prefix this by saying I’m a real noobie to coding…

Confused… I’ve seen some people able to use the height syntax for adjusting frames in tkinter, is there another library ive gotta import or something to use this???

Comment: welcome to stack.  please explain what you mean be `height` syntax ?  do you have code that you need help with,  if so here is a useful guide to asking questions:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: im trying to run this code (heres just a snippit):
        DataFrameRIGHT =Frame(DataFrame, bd=1, width=450, height=300, padx=31, pady=3, relief=RIDGE, bg="Ghost White")
        DataFrameRIGHT.pack(side=RIGHT)

Comment: Please don't post code in the comment section. You can [edit]  your question to include additional details.

Comment: k, so basically ive seen a couple examples where people are able to set the height and width of frames in tkinter, tho upon researching ive come to find out that tkinter (at least what comes built into python) doesnt seem to allow this. when attempting to run code to set height, i get an error : unknown option "-heigth"

Comment: You still have not edited the question with the code. And no, `tkinter.Frame` has a `height` option

Comment: The error in your last comment is about *heigth* (typo), so better check whether same typo is in your code.

Comment: Thanks so much for all ur help, do hope I’m not asking for too much 

Comment: Deltoid euphoria- I was told that I’m not allowed to post code, tho I did I post the error in my one of my previous messages. It may be best to check out the tutorial to better understand the problem I’m experiencing

Comment: Ohh and forgot to mention the time stamp of the relevant part in video: 12:58 , you’ll see the creator can adjust the height of a frame